# Change color and icon of input file component in Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How to change the icon and color of the [`v-file-input`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs) component in Vuetify ?

For v-text-field and other component, the slot approach works, but for this component I can not get it work:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input show-size label="File input">
      <template v-slot:prepend>
         <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
               <v-icon v-on="on" color="yellow lighten-3">
                  notes
               </v-icon>
           </template>
        </v-tooltip>
     </template>
    </v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/yLyMjEp?&editable=true&editors=101).

Comment: Does moving the color to the actual `v-file-input` component, gives the result you're searching for, or do you only want to color the icon?

Comment: I want to colorize the icon (but also set a new icon)

Comment: For adding a new icon use prop prepend-icon

Comment: You are right, it is also what I did above @Riddhi

Answer (score 3):

Because it doesn't have `prepend` slot. You can change icon with `prepend-icon` prop but not the color. You can go to Vuetify Github and make a feature request.

In the meanwhile, you can also use following little hack (works only because you using MDI icons with CSS/webfont)

In your css file:

```css
.mdi-myFileIcon::before {
  content: "\F39A";
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<v-file-input show-size label="File input" prepend-icon="mdi-myFileIcon" />
```

Comment: Didn't think of using CSS, not stupid at all, for a workaround

Comment: @Begueradj  BTW there is [open issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9580) for your problem. You can go like it and watch it for updates....

Comment: My god, you follow everything :) thank you very much for sharing the link.

Comment: I'm just using Vuetify myself so I would like to see it fixed too ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `v-file-input` doesn't utilize the same `slots` as the `v-text-field`, so unfortunately it's actually not possible at the moment, to set the icon the way you're trying.

The options you have to change the color by changing the color of the whole component. And for the icon, you can only change it by using the `prepend-icon` prop.

But this would be an actual feature request to post on the Github of Vuetify, would be great to actually achieve what you want for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will leave my question open for few days just in case if an other code guru says something else :)